# The comment login form is visible to me but not to the user

Tags: comments, comment-form, wp-login-form

I am beginner in wordpress & i am working on my own blog ( http://cssground.com/ ). Right now i am facing an issue with the comment form. The comment form is visible to me & it's work fine but is not visible to the user.

Check this http://cssground.com/?p=30

I want a comment form like [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/07/helvetica-being-fogged-font-aversion-hinders-sight/) have.

Please give your suggestion thanks :)

Comment: I see your comment form, so your statement that it isn't visible to the user in not correct. Please try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have commenting turned off for logged-out users.

To change this setting, visit the *Settings > Discussion* page in your WordPress admin and uncheck the **Users must be registered and logged in to comment** box. Remember to update the setting by clicking the **Save Changes** button.

[image: WordPress Discussion Settings]

Comment: Thanks it's work but now when i submit it's give an error said "Error: You did not add your rating. Hit the BACK button of your Web browser and resubmit your comment with rating."

Comment: I could submit a comment on your site just fine

Comment: I am facing the error issue on localhost may be is a pulgin but thanks for the help